# Transformation from vector to adjacent diagonal matrices

Tags: r, matrix, vector

How can I convert

```
xm<-matrix(c(.1,.2,1),ncol=1)
```

to

```
nd_ylwij
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0  0.0    1    0    0
[2,]  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0    0    1    0
[3,]  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.2    0    0    1
```

This doesn't work, I'm not sure why

```
lapply(as.list(xm),diag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(xm, `*`, diag(length(xm))))
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  I'm noob.  Can you give me a narrative of that command line.  My interpretation is column bind of xm[i] * diag(length(xm)).  Is that right?

Comment: Or `do.call(cbind, lapply(xm , diag, length(xm)))`

Comment: Sure, `lapply` takes every element and multiplies it (`*` is the multiplication function) with the 3-by-3 identity matrix (`diag(length(xm))`), returning a list of matrices. `do.call(cbind, ...)` puts them side-by-side into one wide matrix.